# customizing doxygen preprocessor

Tags: c++, macros, doxygen

I'm new to Doxygen and can't figure out if I am missing a specific step or the code is too difficult for it to parse.  Pretty much every class in this project will `#include <common.hpp>`, where the following is defined:

```
#define DFS_NAMESPACE_BEGIN namespace dfs {
#define DFS_NAMESPACE_END }
```

So for example in class Alg/Thing.hpp

```
#ifndef _DFS_ALG_THING_H
#define _DFS_ALG_THING_H

#include <common.hpp>

DFS_NAMESPACE_BEGIN

class Thing {
    ...
};

DFS_NAMESPACE_END

#endif
```

I've got

- `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING=YES`
- `MACRO_EXPANSION=YES`
- `EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF=NO`
- `SEARCH_INCLUDES=YES`

which based off what the Doxyfile claims should be enough.  I've tried explicitly specifiying the `common.hpp` path, `PREDEFINED`, turning off `SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS`, and a few others without success.  The best I could get `PREDEFINED` to give me, though, was instead of `class Thing` it made it `namespace Thing`.

Namespaces *do* work as expected if I just write them out instead of using the above `define`, but I'd like to keep this macro (or perhaps replace it with a similar one?) for readability.

Is this fixable? Is there another way to maybe just raw text-replace the `DFS_NAMESPACE_*` or something? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this shouldn't be necessary, but I was able to get it working with

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
PREDEFINED             = DFS_NAMESPACE_BEGIN="namespace dfs {"
PREDEFINED            += DFS_NAMESPACE_END="}"
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES
```

I think I had a problem with the original `PREDEFINED` enumeration, I escaped it with `\` but I think the leading whitespace may have caused issues?

Just a little frustrating because I don't want to have to enumerate all of the macros I want in the Doxyfile.  Hopefully somebody benefits from this someday though.